# Trying to get python to work

Tags: tar

I'm in linux. The Python (version 3.6.7)is in my linux operating system and I have fetched all the libs & tk. The next step would be for me to go to downloads then tar. I type the following: cd download to get in that directory. I get an error that nothing is in the directory. What am I doing wrong? I also tried cd downloads/.

Comment: What is "linux"? Ubuntu has "Downloads", not "download" or "downloads".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I cannot uncompress the file linux.hla.tar.gz because the computer cannot find the file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/629590/i-cannot-uncompress-the-file-linux-hla-tar-gz-because-the-computer-cannot-find-t)

Answer (score 1):

Linux file system is case-sensitive. Try `cd Downloads`. If you want to get a list of all files and directories in your current working directory, type `ls`.